# Nomenclature for water management objects

Tags: drainage

Building roofs and parking lots cause prevent rain from naturally entering the ground.   A bird's eye view of a building shows a footprint where water can not drain into the ground and must drain into non-footprint areas.  Other objects such as tiled patios can effectively increase the footprint of roofs and parking lots.

A larger 'object footprint' reduces the area for natural draining.

**What is the correct term for 'object footprint', which prevents natural draining and its complement: land that permits natural draining of water?**

Answer (score 1):

[Impervious Surface Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impervious_surface) is the term you are looking for. The opposite - land that allows water to flow through - is technically "pervious" but more commonly referred to as "permeable".

Comment: Excellent reference.  After reading it I would think Impermeable would be an apt term, though it probably makes sense to use standard terms.  thank you.

Comment: One of the projects I work on for a customer has data for it in their building facility database, so I knew what to look for.